# React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string warning in unit testing with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I am unit testing my react-native app. I have a login page which consist of a component and has following props passed from container component.

[image]

I am doing snapshot testing with jest and enzyme. I passed these props to Login Component like this

```
import Login from "../index";
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import globalStyles from '../../../../../global/styles';

let theme = 'DefaultTheme', wrapper;

const createTestProps = (props) => ({
    navigation: {
        navigate: jest.fn()
    },
    theme: theme,
    globalStyles: globalStyles(theme),
    session: {},
    changeScene: jest.fn(),
    changeTheme: jest.fn(),
    setUser: jest.fn(),
    logout: jest.fn(),
    ...props
});
beforeEach(() => {
    const props = createTestProps({});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(props));
    wrapper = shallow(<Login {...props} />);
});
test('should render login component correctly', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Test passed and snapshot is created however this warning is shown in console.

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: object.

I check the export type it is default one.

```
export default Login
```

The global style object is a nested style object mainly consist of styles for button, text etc and it passed as a prop in every component of my app. Need help what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: so for some reason `import Login from '../index';` does not return anything. it may be for different reason, e.g. to me it happened also because of dependencies cycled and did not resolved by babel at the moment. are other tests for different components working well?

Comment: But I see snapshot jsx generated.

Comment: hm, interesting. So it's not `Login` is broken otherwise it will not construct any tree to be snapshot-ed later.

Comment: Its the global style object that causing the issue.